# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unexpected status line in ArcGISHttpClientHandler+NativeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

While getting the image details with attachments of the Asset an exception is thrown while calling Attachment.GetDataAsync(); but not able to recreate the same again. the issue came in android. ArcGIS runtime version is 100.13

ArcGISHttpClientHandler+NativeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean isRetry)
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified.

```
Attachment.GetDataAsync();
```

Comment: so this has happened once and you're unable to recreate it?

Comment: yes this has happened once and able to trace in appcenter but unable to recreate it

Comment: ArcGISHttpClientHandler+NativeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Boolean isRetry)
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
faced another exception but this time with an Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 200 OK. why these exceptions are occurring,   please help to resolve the issues